# Ndef.getType() return the string as 'org.nfcforum.ndef.type2', but i want in this type 'NFC_FORUM_TYPE_2'

Tags: android, nfc

I want to get the Tag type... so i used the code like

```
Tag myTag = (Tag) nfcintent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(myTag);
String NFCType =ndefTag.getType();
```

the result comes like
NFCType= org.nfcforum.ndef.type2

but i want to show result as 'NFC_FORUM_TYPE_2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how bout use if condition...if(type = "org.nfcforum.ndef.type2"){type = "NFC_FORUM_TYPE_2"}...

Comment: Is If condition is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible return values of `Ndef.getType()` are:

```
 "org.nfcforum.ndef.type1"
 "org.nfcforum.ndef.type2"
 "org.nfcforum.ndef.type3"
 "org.nfcforum.ndef.type4"
 "com.nxp.ndef.mifareclassic"
 "com.nxp.ndef.icodesli"
```

If you want anything else than this, you will have to define that yourself (e.g. using a [`HashMap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)), based on these return values.